# How to tell what is a method and what is an object constructor in this class in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm a beginner in Python and PySide. Can someone explain me how to recognize what is an object constructor and what is a method in this class (e.g. QLCDNumber(self) vs addWidget(argv)) and therefore why not calling self.vbox instead of vbox?

```
import sys 
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class App(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        lcd = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self)
        sld = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(lcd)
        vbox.addWidget(sld)
```

Comment: As I understand it __init__() is the object constructor because it is a special class method for this functionality as documented at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html. init_ui() is a non-special class method.

Comment: If you want to access instance attributes you must _always_ go for the dotted notation. `lcd`, `sld` and `vbox` are simple variables of `init_ui` and,  since they all seem to go out of scope at the end of the function without any further references to them, they will get garbage collected. IOW, `init_ui` probably does nothing.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, keep in mind that \__xyz__ double underscore methods are often called *magic methods* and provide special services.   For example \__str__ is roughly equivalent to a Java *toString*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between "methods" and "object constructors" in Python is very thin. You must be getting thoroughly confused with Java here.

Consider this:

```
class A():
  def __init__(self, bar):
    baz = bar + bar
    self.egg = baz + baz

def B(tuna):
  return A(tuna)
```

What happens is `baz` is a mere variable and only `egg` hangs around after `A.__init__()` ends.

```
>>> A("foo").egg
"foofoofoofoo"
>>> A("foo").baz # exception
```

Also, the return values of `A()` and `B()` are indistinguishable.

In Python, way moreso than Java, *everything* is an object and with a few corner cases there is no distinction between functions and methods. If you *really really really* did need to check, this is the way to go:

```
>>> import types
>>> type(A) == types.ClassType and type(B) != types.ClassType
True
>>> type(A) != types.FunctionType and type(B) == types.FunctionType
True
>>> type(A.__init__) == types.MethodType and type(B) != types.MethodType
True
```

...but the need to do such introspection is quite rare.

Answer (score 1):

Class constructors are defined by the method `__init__`. All non-static class methods (including the constructor) take a reference to the object itself in the form the `self` parameter, which is the first parameter passed.

You'd create a new instance of the `App` class by doing the following:

```
app = App()
```

Then to call the method `init_ui` you'd do the following:

```
app.init_ui()
```

If `lcd`, `sld` and `vbox` are all member variables of the `App` class then you'll need to access them as `self.vbox` within the methods.

Comment: Are `lcd`, `sld` and `vbox`  in this example, now member variables? If not, does `self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()` makes it a member variable?

Comment: In your example they are just local variables, if you want to access the object's variables, you have to use `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor `__init__()` is called when you initialise the class

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        print("example")
    def init(self):
        print("example No. 2")
```

So:

```
>>>a = example
... "example"
>>>a.init()
... "example No. 2"
```

The  `self` is something that class have stored inside itself, not globaly but it will not 'disaper'

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, gender, name):
        self.age = 0
        self.gender = gender
        self.name = name
    def aging(self):
        self.age += 1

humans = []
humans.append(Human("male", "Jack")) # his age is 0 and gender is male
humans.append(Human("female", "Jesica"))
for human in humans:
    human.aging() # age is increasing
```

Comment: I have read that `__init__`  in Python is not a constructor because instance is already created when `__init__` is called. However, my question is not about that. I don't know to recognize is `QGridLayout()` a method or a class/object? My english is bad, that is why my question is unclear

Comment: From what I understand /class Human/ is a class /myhuman = human/ is an object and /aging(self)/ is a method

Comment: @HrvojeT unless you are dealing with immutable objects, the difference between `__init__` and constructors is mostly immaterial. You can't tell whether `QGridLayout` is a function or a class based on syntax alone. Consider what happens when I write `import QGridLayout as _QGridLayout; def QGridLayout(): return _QGridLayout()`